# convert specific html table columns to excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have 4 columns of data in the HTML table.

```
Index Age Gender Height 
1      10   M     4 
2      23   F     5.6
```

I am trying to export the Age and Gender or Gender and Height columns to excel using javascript.
Here is the .csv converter but I am trying to convert to excel. It is displaying whole columns data in a single column with comma separating in each column data


Download list

```
  function exportData(){
      /* Get the HTML data using Element by Id */
      var table = document.getElementById("tblStocks");
  
      /* Declaring array variable */
      var rows =[];
  
        //iterate through rows of table
      for(var i=0,row; row = table.rows[i];i++){
          //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
          //Get each cell value/column from the row
          column1 = row.cells[0].innerText;
          column2 = row.cells[1].innerText;
          column3 = row.cells[2].innerText;
          column4 = row.cells[3].innerText;
  
      /* add a new records in the array */
          rows.push(
              [
                  column1,
                  column2,
                  column3,
                  column4
              ]
          );
  
          }
          csvContent = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8,";
          rows.forEach(function(rowArray){
              row = rowArray.join(",");
              csvContent += row + "\r\n";
          });
  
          /* create a hidden <a> DOM node and set its download attribute */
          var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
          var link = document.createElement("a");
          link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
          link.setAttribute("download", "Report_Result.xls");
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          /* download the data file named "Stock_Price_Report.csv" */
          link.click();
  }
  </script>
```

Here is the excel convert but it isn't working either

```
<script>

    function ExportToExcel(type, fn, dl) {
        var elt = document.getElementById('tblStocks');
        var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(elt, { sheet: "report" });
        return dl ?
            XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: type, bookSST: true, type: 'base64' }) :
            XLSX.writeFile(wb, fn || ('Report_result.' + (type || 'xlsx')));
    }

</script>
```

What I want in excel as

```
Age Gender 
10    M
23    F

or 

Gender  Height 
  M       4
  F      5.6
```